# How do you change the name shown in Windows Task Manager for a running process, in particular for sub-processes?

Tags: windows, winapi, process, taskmanager

Unlike on Linux or macOS, I haven't been able to find an API to change the process name of a running process (or in the case I care about, a sub-process). I'd want it to still appear under the main program (which I don't care about changing).

I need to do this from within the program, not from a batch script or by hand.

Note that Edge appears to do this, so there must be a way -- but it might be a hidden/non-public API...

There have a been a few questions in roughly similar areas, but no answers other than manually changing it, which obviously isn't happening with Edge.

Comment: If you mean https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2021/10/12/improving-edge-processes-task-manager/ then I don't think this API is public. Task manager is well known for using mostly undocumented functions to gather its data...

Comment: It is obviously an undocumented API, probably something in beta that Microsoft is testing until they decide to release it publically for everyone to use. One easy way I could think of this being implemented would be a new attribute option for `STARTUPINFOEX` for `CreateProcess...()`, for instance. But that is just a guess.